# Ruby on Rails 2.3.8: How do I do a custom SQL query, returned as an object / ActiveRecord object, rather than a hash?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Le code:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("Le Query")
```

The above will return a hash formatted as such:

```
{"name"=>"title", "sequence"=>"0", "body"=>"", "section_id"=>"74", "id"=>"325", "revision"=>"2"}
```

Now, normally, if just do `ModelName.find(conditions)`, i'll get something like the following:

```
#<ObjectName id: 272, name: "title", body: "", sequence: 0, section_id: 89, revision: 0>
```

Now, is there a way to convert the hash to a format such that if the hash is stored in variable "`a`", I could do something like:

```
a.name
```

like it was an active record object, rather than

```
a["name"]
```

as I do currently with the above hash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyModel.find_by_sql("Le Query")`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
a = ModelName.new(ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("Le Query"))
```

Comment: ah, kinda. it won't let me set teh ID... which I need to do for views, and for my whole feature to be DRY. The error: WARNING: Can't mass-assign these protected attributes: id

Comment: try pulling the id out of the hash and set it into the object afterwards?